# Specflow Step Argument Transformation Regex doesn't match

Tags: selenium, specflow

I'm new to Specflow so this might be a noob question but I've tested my regex and I'm pretty sure it should match my input.

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b&i=Name%2c+Sku+Name%2c+Person

I have this in my feature file

And Select columns *Name,Sku Name, Place Name*

My Step definition:

```
    [When(@"Select columns (.*)")]
    public void WhenSelectTheColumnsToInclude(string[] columns)
    {
    }
```

And finally my custom argument transform

```
    [StepArgumentTransformation(@"\w[^,]+")]
    public string[] CommaSeperatedListTransform(string names)
    {
    }
```

So as I said the regex is legit but I guess Specflow is expecting something else as well?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Cannot cast string to string[]. Also, if I put a breakpoint in my transform function it never hits it.

Comment: have you tried changing your `string[]` to `List<string>` just in case its something weird with the array...